# What are the reasons to use the id attribute for CSS purposes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've always used the `class` attribute, never `id` *for the purpose of CSS selecting and styling*. I know that the `id` must be unique, but that doesn't seem to be a reason to use it for CSS.

The only reason I have used the `id` attribute is for JavaScript and form labelling.

I find mixing `id` and `class` for the purpose of CSS can cause confusion, and for me it's a good way to force separation of style and behaviour.

Is there a good reason to use `id` for CSS purposes? Is there anything that can be achieved with `id` that can't be done with `class`?

**Comments I found useful/interesting**

- You could say the same thing about classes. There's lots of JavaScript out there that does (and must) target elements of a specific class. Changing the class in those instances is just as problematic from a behavior standpoint. - AaronSieb
- IDs have different specificity in the cascade than classes. - Killroy
- Using ID for styling makes sense if it's an element that doesn't have duplicate, especially if it's something that shows up in all/most pages - RichN

Comment: Found a nice post related to this: http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

Comment: this is a quote from that article: "It is important to note that, although an ID is technically faster and more performant, it is barely so. Using Steve Souders’ CSS Test Creator we can see that an ID selector and a class selector show very little difference in reflow speed."  I don't think that processing efficiency should be your main concern unless you're dealing with a LOT of data (eg. you are Google).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason I use ID tags is to communicate with people who are reading my code.  Specifically, the ID tag makes it easy to reference whatever specific element they want to with complete peace of mind, knowing that any changes they make to it will only affect that one element.

There is also a more technical reason to use ID tags that you may not know.  This information can be quite enlightening for those who are new to CSS.

The following outline illustrates exactly how the "cascading" nature of Cascading Style Sheets works. In this outline, start by comparing 2 CSS styles based on the uppermost criteria of the outline, ie "1. Winner = **!important declaration**."  If one style is of higher priority than the other in that aspect, it wins.  If they are the same in that aspect, continue down to the next criteria in until you find the differentiating factor.

1. Winner = **!important declaration**.

   - Eg. `#some-element {color: blue !important;}` beats `#some-element {color: red;}`.
2. Winner = **Inline CSS**.

   - Eg.:

     - `<div id="some-element" style="color: yellow;}">some content</div>`beats...
     - `<style type="text/css">#some-element {color: red;}</style>` and...
     - `<link type="text/css" link rel="stylesheet" href="set-some-element-color-to-blue.css"/>`.
3. Winner = Greatest # of **ID** selectors.

   - Eg. `#some-element#id-2 {color: blue;}` beats `#some-element {color: red;}`.
4. Winner = Greatest # of **class**, **pseudo-class**, and **other attribute** selectors.

   - Eg. `.some-elements.class-2 {color: blue;}` beats `.some-elements {color: red;}`.
5. Winner = Greatest # of **element names** and **pseudo-elements** in the selector.

   - Eg. `#some-element:hover {color: blue;}` beats `#some-element {color: red;}`.
6. Winner = **Most recently read** by the machine.

   - Eg.:

     - `<style type="text/css">#some-element {color: red;}</style>` beats...
     - `<link type="text/css" link rel="stylesheet" href="set-some-element-color-to-blue.css"/>` because **internal CSS** is read after **external CSS**.

Answer (score 21):

Using ID for styling makes sense if it's an element that doesn't have duplicate, especially if it's something that shows up in all/most pages.

E.g.:

- Page header & footer
- Search box (the thing you can see up there)
- Navigation list (something like the thing on the right)

Comment: I'd add the caveat, "assuming that it would never make sense for this element to appear more than once", as opposed to "just doesn't happen to appear more than once in any example I've come up with so far". So like a page header? Yes. Ad box, because right now I only have one customer who's bought an ad? No.

Comment: to support the OP's argument: the elements (like header/footer, search box) can also be styled using CSS classes and technically achieve the same results. The real point here is readability: using IDs for styling makes it *clear to the reader of the css* that this element is unique for each page. using ID's in CSS is a way to write more expressive code.

Comment: "There's only one of them in a document" isn't a _reason_ to use the id attribute. That's just a requirement for using it.

Comment: That's like saying you should use a unicycle because it has one wheel. It says nothing about the utility of it.

Answer (score 10):

Selecting anything with a unique id is faster than selecting with a class. The difference is negligible, but in applications with huge amounts of DOM elements, or intensive Javascript application, it makes a difference.

For example if you are using jQuery check this out: [jquery performance rules](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/)

Comment: I don't have a problem with using ids for JavaScript, I just don't know why people use them for CSS styling.

Comment: Well even with css you have some issues, for example IE6 has trouble with 2 css classes on the same element. If you have an element with class="test hidden", and you have a css selector of test.hidden, a bug appears in IE6 in which it has trouble selecting the element.

Comment: I stopped worrying about IE6 a long time ago :-) For the sites I run I just don't get enough traffic from IE6 users.

Comment: Upvoted this, then realised you're talking about javascript. Selecting an element with a unique ID is also faster in CSS! In other words, the browser can find and render the element quicker.

Answer (score 8):

No, but if your element has an `id` why not use it for styling?

You could say the same thing about element names - there's nothing you can do with `p` that you couldn't do with `class='paragraph'`. That doesn't mean it's a good idea to add `class='paragraph'` to every `<p>` element.

Comment: I haven't voted on it (can't down-vote anyway), but to be honest, I don't really see your point :-) I use IDs for JavaScript, I could use that same ID for CSS, but I find that mixes style and behaviour which I prefer to keep separate to avoid issues in future (removal of ID means the styling goes away too).

Comment: My point is - if your element has an ID already, and there you want that particular element to have a style - why add a class? There's already a way to style it.

Comment: @Rew You could say the same thing about classes.  There's lots of JavaScript out there that does (and must) target elements of a specific class.  Changing the class in those instances is just as problematic from a behavior standpoint.

Answer (score 5):

IDs *identify*, classes *classify*. This point has been mentioned several times here, more or less.

An example would be:

```
<div class="author" id="stephen">[...]</div>
```

From a CSS specificity standpoint, targeting IDs will make CSS rules more specific than rules with classes, even several classes.

Thus:

```
p#recent {}
```

is more specific than

```
body>p.news.recent {}
```

and when a user agent finds both of these, the first will prevail.

Answer (score 4):

You don't HAVE to use IDs.  There is no design that you can create using IDs that you can't create using classes.

With that said, using an ID has the advantage of clearly labeling a selector as applying to exactly one element in a page.  I typically use them for styling elements in my page templates (#Content, #Navigation, etc.).

In general, I would try to use it in areas that allow me to make the markup more concise.  When a selector can be targeted at a tag, you should use the tag.  When it can be targeted at an ID, use the ID.  Otherwise, use a class.

But, again, whether or not you use IDs isn't terribly important.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to think of the relationship of `id` and `class` in HTML as analogous to object-oriented programming: an `id` is like an instance of a `class`.

I use classes more than I use ids, and often use multi-class selectors (e.g. `.film.drama`). But if I do want to identify a particular element, so that I can apply specific styling or behaviour, then I'll assign an `id`, and often a `class` as well. E.g.

```
<ul>
    <li class="film drama">A</li>
    <li class="book drama">B</li>
    <li class="film documentary" id="film-9832">C</li>
</ul>
```

In assigning an id, I think "could it ever make sense for there to be more than one of these on the page". If the answer is yes, then I'd probably go for a class instead.

As a result, and as @RichN and @AaronSieb have mentioned, I often use id's for specific page elements that are certain to be present only once on the page:

```
<ul class="sidebar" id="site-meta">[...]</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple elements of the same class and need to specify a different style for one or more of them that'd seem pretty valid to me.

Comment: This is why you can attach multiple CSS classes to an object, though.

Comment: Why not use multiple classes? class='genericClass specificClass' etc.

Comment: Why not use inline styles? Why not use font tags?

Comment: multiple classes are not fully supported by all common browsers yet. Also, IDs have different specificity in the cascade then classes.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of to use an ID is if you have a specificity war - two elements with the same specificity. Applying an ID will give your element a higher specificity - +100 to be exact.

So, in the case where you have two styles defined with equal specificity, you may want to 'clobber' one by applying a higher specificity to the other. That being said, you can achieve the same by applying a more specific class to that selector too, which would increase the specificity by 10.

ID = 100 (#foo)
class = 10 (.bar)
element = 1 (div)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, using ID-based styles is a bad idea.

IDs, being unique, *should* only occur up-to 1 time within your DOM.  This limits the use of any ID-related style to up-to 1 time.

CSS classes, on the other hand, can be used multiple times or not at all.

Frankly, I think ID should be used for behavior, and class should be used for style.  The fact that you can use them interchangeably is part of what makes some aspects of web development inconsistent.

Comment: Yes - but one time in every document that references your stylesheet. Still worth adding a style for IMHO. I always do styles on IDs for components of pages that I know there are just one of. That's what IDs are for.

Comment: I think the OP is trying to understand why you would use one over the other.  Sure, you _can_ define a style by ID, but it limits the scope in which that style is available.  This is why I think it's a poor design, I can't think of a scenario where I feel like I need to seal a style like that.

Comment: Why do you think there are different needs for behaviour and styling? Aren't methods of selection independent of what you do with them? If you have ever used jQuery you will see that classes are very useful for behaviour. Like flash all images or scale all paragraphs. For example there is a common technique to have menu selected-ness as part of the CSS by applying an id to the body tag and cross referencing it to a class on a menu item.

Comment: So JM you're basically saying I must use <div id="foo" class="bar"></div> because using <div id="foo"></div> and then styling #foo{} is a bad idea? Do you really think redundant markup is a great idea?

Comment: @JM - RichN's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607839/is-there-any-valid-reason-to-use-the-id-attribute-for-css-purposes/1607961#1607961) has excellent examples when you might want to do this.

Comment: @Killroy, squeeks.  As I mentioned, I don't like to seal off my styles.  ID is an awesome, fast selector and class is useful for pinpointing the element(s) you want to act on.  Won't you agree that styles can often be interpreted as behavior?  Why not separate the ID from the style so as to improve readability?

Comment: How many other elements do you think I'll want to give the exact same appearance and positioning as my top navbar? There's no reason why "ID should be used for behavior." That's a baseless opinion.

Comment: Why is it that "designers" who invent and espouse these arbitrary little rules with no basis in reality always have such unattractive websites?

Answer (score 0):

I use a id when i know im going to use javascript on that specific element. ID's are much faster then classes in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use ID's for static page elements (headers, footers). Reason being page weight.

id="h" is lighter than class="h".

Every byte counts in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why I use ids in CSS is for layout. If I have one header and footer, then:

```
#header
{
...
...
...
}

#footer
{
...
...
...
}
```

Or one wrapper for my main content, or one right sidebar. If someone decides they like my layout and want to view source, it's easy to see.